# Parse String in Restify

Tags: json, node.js, restify

For the following JSON file

```
{
"_id":"1",
"Time":"03:20:22"
}
```

I want to add hours such that "Time" + 2 = "05:20:22";

Using Restify, I do not know how to parse this JSON into caculatable format because if I do data.Time.split(":"); restify does not recognize this command.

How should I parse Strings like "03:20:11" so that I can add number of hours to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following sample code: (Make sure `data.Time` is a string while you retrieve object from restify. Because split function works only on strings)

```
x= "03:20:22";

y=x.split(':')

z=int(y[0])+2

y[0]=str(z)

print y
```